# Get FloatingActionButton background color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Good night.

How do I get the background color of a FloatingActionButton? I'm using Android Studio with java language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the very first method in the documentation:

[getBackgroundTintList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#getBackgroundTintList())

Just use

```
fab.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor();
```

Comment: I was using the Background property, I switched to BackgroundTint and it worked. Thank you.